# Number of gas molecules in activated state vs normal state

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

I have a simple bimolecular reaction

$$\ce{A + M <=>[k_2][k_1] A^* + M}\tag{1}$$

where $\ce{A}$ is a molecule which collides with another molecule $\ce{M}$. $\ce{A^*}$ is the $\ce{A}$ molecule in the activated state. $k_2$ is the reaction rate constant in the forward direction and $k_1$ is the reaction rate constant in the reverse direction.

The activated complex then forms the product by the following reaction where $k_3$ is the reaction rate constant.

$$\ce{A^* ->[k_3] P}\tag{2}$$

For this mechanism it's said that at low pressures $k_3 > k_2$ and vice versa at high pressures. Now according to Le Chatelier's principle at low pressures the system moves to produce more gas molecules and vice versa.

Now at low pressures, by low pressures I mean lowering the pressure from a set pressure, $P$, reaction step 1 will move to produce more gas molecules. But when we are comparing  $\ce{A}$  and  $\ce{A^*}$, which one will have more gas molecules i.e how to deduce in which direction will the step 1 move in response to stresses in terms of more pressure and less pressure?

Comment: A*/A will probably follow the Boltzman distribution E=E0.exp(-Ea/kT), eventually shifted due reaction entropy change. As both (1) and (2) are supposed to be in equilibrium, (2) would have zero net effect on (1). If (2) has not reach equilibrium by P production yet, the ration A*/A would be even smaller.

Comment: Sorry Poutnik step 2 is not supposed to be in equilibrium. I have edited the question.

Comment: So IMHO [A*]/[A] < [A*]/[A](eq) < 1 // BTW are you sure you mean by K1,K2,K3  equilibrium constants and not kinetic rate constants ?

Comment: Instead of \`K3\` `K3`, use should rather use \$K_3\$  $K_3$ to follow the proper typography. // You can find useful  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Yes I meant kinetic reaction rate constant. I have edited in the question. What do you mean by IMHO [A*]/[A] < [A*]/[A](eq) < 1? Can you please clarify?

Comment: I assume you are familiar with basics of algebra. [A] means molar concentration of A, but it can be replaced by partial pressure, as I have forgotten you probably speak about gaseous phase.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't what IMHO meant ,I got that you are saying in equilibrium [A*]/[A] will be more than [A*]/[A], but how did they assume at low pressures K3>K2 and at high pressures K3>K2? If you could clarify that it would be very helpful for me to understand the mechanism going on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129352/discussion-between-poutnik-and-obiwan).

Comment: This is the Lindemann mechanism for unimolecular reactions, second order at low pressure and first order at high pressures. There is no need to think about Le Chatelier as this can be analysed exactly to answer your questions. Any decent phys. chem. text book will describe this .